# Hive INSERT OVERWRITE showing error

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata

I am working on a example of integrating hbase-0.98.19 with hive-1.2.1. I have created a table in hbase using the command

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_emp(id int, name string, role string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" =     ":key,cf1:name,cf1:role")
 TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp");
```

Then I created 'testemp' for importing data to 'hbase_table_emp'. The below code shows the method to create the 'testemp' table

```
create table testemp(id int, name string, role string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';
load data local inpath '/home/hduser/sample.txt' into table testemp;
select * from testemp;
```

Till now, everything works fine. But when I run the command `insert overwrite table hbase_table_emp select * from testemp;`

I get the following error:-

> hive> insert overwrite table hbase_table_emp select * from testemp;
>   Query ID = hduser_20160613131557_ddef0b47-a773-477b-94d2-5cc070eb0de6
>   Total jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks is set
>   to 0 since there's no reduce operator java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.checkOutputSpecs(FileSinkOperator.java:1117)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormatImpl.checkOutputSpecs(HiveOutputFormatImpl.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:564)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:431)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:137)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createHiveOutputFormat(FileSinkOperator.java:1139)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.checkOutputSpecs(FileSinkOperator.java:1114)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must
>   specify table name    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.common.util.ReflectionUtil.setConf(ReflectionUtil.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.common.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveOutputFormat(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveOutputFormat(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:267)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createHiveOutputFormat(FileSinkOperator.java:1137)
>     ... 38 more Job Submission failed with exception
>   'java.io.IOException(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name)' FAILED:
>   Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask `

PS: I have hbase.jar , zookeeper.jar and guava.jar included in the CLASSPATH.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For Hive HBase integration, in order to insert data into the hbase table, you need to also specify the hbase.mapred.output.outputtable in the TBLPROPERTIES.

[Hive HBase Integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)

> The hbase.mapred.output.outputtable property is optional; it's needed
>   if you plan to insert data to the table (the property is used by
>   hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat)

So for your table you would need to run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "emp");
```